# Can not get good value for display

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

About function: it is checked that user has new point (if yes then swal is active) or not.

And what I wrote (or I wanted to write)

The function showNewPoints is in ngOnInit for launch everytime that user is logged. Next, i connect to the database for getting NIP (its ID).

Next I check that user I received is exist, If yes then i connect to database for get 3 value (first and second is for checked that value is other then real point and real false point (the false point is sum of all point that user has in database but they are unactive - it will be active when user pay for product)

So next I want to sum all points which are unactive.
I connect again to the database, get all data of history (there is the active and inactive point) and save I to the holder.
At next step, i look in this holder all data that are unactive (there return false so looking for false status) and I wanted to save all of that in falsePoint.

Next, I just checked that the values are other and if they are not okey, the swal print message.

After that, i just update the values that are checked for compromise.

And it is don not work...
The message print but it shows NaN for falsePoint. When I change the

```
falsePoint += parseInt(holder.point, 10);
```

to

```
 falsePoint = parseInt(holder.point, 10);
```

It shows the lasted on that it's 333.

What I make wrong? Where is the problem? I get the good data from oldPoint, oldFalsePoint and Pointed. But the problem is after this.

```
showNewPoints() {
let oldFalsePoint;
let falsePoint;
let Pointed;
let oldPointed
let holder;

if(this.curretlyUser) {

  firebase.database().ref().child('/user').on('child_added', (snapshot) => {
    for(let i in snapshot.val()) {
      if(this.curretlyUser == snapshot.val().email) {
        this.userName = snapshot.val().nip;
        if(this.userName) {
          firebase.database().ref('/user/').child(this.userName).on('value', (snapshot) => {
            oldPointed = snapshot.val().oldpoint;
            oldFalsePoint = snapshot.val().oldFalsePoint;
            Pointed = snapshot.val().point;
          })
        }
        console.log(this.userName);
        firebase.database().ref('/user/').child(this.userName + '/history') .on('child_added', (snapshot) => {
          holder = snapshot.val();
        })
        for(let i in holder) {
          if(!holder.isActive) {
            falsePoint = parseInt(holder.point, 10);
            console.log(falsePoint);
          }
        }
        if(Pointed > oldPointed || falsePoint > oldFalsePoint) {
          swal({
            title: "Właśnie naliczyliśmy punkty na Twoje konto. Masz teraz:",
            text: Pointed + " " + "punktów aktywnych <br>" +
                  falsePoint + " " + "punktów nieaktywnych",
            html: true
          });

          firebase.database().ref('/user/').child(this.userName).update({
            oldpoint: Pointed,
            oldFalsePoint: falsePoint
          })
        }
      }
    }
  })
}
```

}

Edit
Now it is working. I rebuild the whole function and it is look like below.
And also i find why i can not add the value. Becouse when i add number to falsePoint it is added in js undfine + 33. I just set falsePoint = 0 and it start work :) Also i make less connection to firebase.

```
showNewPoints() {
let user = this.curretlyUser;
let falsePoint: number = 0;
let oldPointed, oldFalsePoint, Pointed;
let nip;

if(this.curretlyUser) {

  let ref = firebase.database().ref('/user').orderByChild("email").equalTo(user);
  let history;

  ref.once('child_added', (snap) => {
    nip = snap.val().nip;
    history = snap.val().history;
    oldPointed = snap.val().oldpoint;
    oldFalsePoint = snap.val().oldFalsePoint;
    Pointed = snap.val().point;
  }).then(()=>{
    for(let point in history) {
      if(!history[point].isActive) {
        falsePoint += history[point].point;
      }
    }
  }).then(()=>{
    if(Pointed > oldPointed || falsePoint > oldFalsePoint) {
      swal({
        title: "Właśnie naliczyliśmy punkty na Twoje konto. Masz teraz:",
        text: Pointed + " " + "punktów aktywnych <br>" +
              falsePoint + " " + "punktów nieaktywnych",
        html: true
      });
    }
  }).then(()=>{
   firebase.database().ref('/user/').child(nip).update({
      oldpoint: Pointed,
      oldFalsePoint: falsePoint
    })
  })
}
```

}